# Why FutureBuilder never reload data when it changed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I try to upload an image inside FutuerBuilder in flutter but nothing happen to the UI. I have to leave the current page and enter it again to see changes. That is happenn in uploading the image, but when I delete it the FutuerBuilder updated directly.

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: future,
      initialData: const [],
      builder: (context, imagesSnapshot) {
     if (imagesSnapshot.data == null) {
         return const Center(
             child: Text("..."),
        );
     }else if (imagesSnapshot.hasError){
        return const Center(child: Icon(Icons.error),);
         } else {
           final images = imagesSnapshot.data!
               .where((element)=> element["collectionId"] == collections[i].collectionId);
    } 
  }
)
```

I tried to use setState to re-build the page but it did not. Also I tried to load the data from the server but nothing happen.

Comment: Did you use initState() and dispose() method?

Comment: Yes, I just used  initState() to initialise future.

Comment: Maybe you've to use future = fetchMethod(); under initState()

Comment: Does the future actually complete?

Comment: I just remove initState and put the future directly inside FutureBuilder. and I reload the future after uploading done, and that worked.

Comment: @Corner now it will recall the every time you call set State, if you need to rebuild the futureBuilder, just reassign the `future=yourMethod` and call setState. or you may like StreamBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed initState and I put the future directly inside the FutureBuilder. and I reload the data agin after uploading has done, and that worked.